# is there any easy-to-use cluster building software?

Tags: cluster-computing

Assume there are several computers, distributed in the same network.
I install a program on all of them, and so there is a cluster.
and I can log in it, run my application(like web server , db server, and so on).
I don't need to configure the IPs, don't need to balance the loading.

Is there any software like this now?

edit:
OK, I want to build a cluster that can provide an enterprise web server(also db server store data), we have lots of PC, they are only running a small program now(for shop floor work-flow control). I want to use the additional CPU and Disk resource to build a service.

Answer (score 1):

What purpose are you planning to serve with your cluster? That will determine the tool you want to use.

That being said, you will have to do some configuration- like IPs, Authentication Mechanism, et cetra. If you don not tell it what you want, how will it know?

Answer (score 0):

In general, if the application is not designed to be clustered, you will have more pain than advantages.

Is current load too high for current single box hardware?